# php move_uploaded_file, image turns to small red x icon when moved

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload images and transfer them immediately to a specific folder.

Here's my code:

```
    $file_path = "assets/placervw_photo/";
    $file_path = $file_path . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
```

The page displays "success" but when I check the folder, it contains the file, having the same filename and file type, but it turns into a smal red X icon with white background. Here's a look: http://s14.postimg.org/ifoiyzde5/red_x.png

I have tested it to jpg and png files and they had the same outcome.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

The "little red X" is your browser way of saying "There's no image here".

Are you trying to **display** the image in the same page in which you upload it? You **cannot**. You already sent some content which is not image, so trying to signal the browser "I've got an image here" would get you a tiny red X.

You need to send a IMG URL with the proper URL prefix:

```
$url = "http://yourserver.com/path/to/".$file_path;

echo "Success, here's your image: <img src=\"$url\" />";
```

You'd probably also do well to not trust the user's file name, but assign a random ID of your choice, and also verify that it **is** indeed an image (you can use `getImageSize()`, also to verify the extension matches the MIME type). Just in case someone sends you a 'picture' called "../../../pwn3d.php": it's been known to happen.